# Update error in Virtual Box

Tags: updates, virtualbox

When I update my Ubuntu, appear

```
W:Failed to fetch http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/lucid/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'non-free/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What can I do for fix this error on my Virtual Box?

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you on?

Comment: In addition to Goddard's question, what version of VirtualBox?  And had you installed Guest Additions in the Ubuntu environment?

Comment: My version is 4.2.18 and I don't know if Guest Additions is installed in my Ubuntu. How can I install?

Comment: My Ubuntu is 12 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using the wrong distribution codename in the `sources.list` file.

I personally prefer to have a separate file for each 3rd party repository, you can create one for virtualbox using the following in CLI:

```sh
sudo echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian `lsb_release -sc` contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
```

After creating `virtualbox.list`, remove or comment out the out-dated line from your `sources.list`.

It may look like this => `deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian lucid contrib non-free`.

Once done, update your system `sudo apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is an invalid entry in /etc/apt/sources.list file. There is no source package in the VirtualBox source repository. Just remove the deb-src line:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Remove or comment this line:

```
deb-src http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian lucid non-free
```

This should solve the case.